# Is there anyway to know any database collection had been updated in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB installed on my computer.

Suppose I have many databases in that. (i.e databases name A,B,C,D...)

And each database contains some collections. (i.e. Database A has collections person, student, course, etc. Similarly, other databases have collections too.)

Now at a particular time, I want to get to know which collections of which database had been updated.
(i.e. Database B had a collection person which had been updated)

Is there any way to get to know that? It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB [Auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/) could be what you are looking for. Please note that it requires MongoDB Enterprise version.

If you do not have/do not want enterprise edition, an alternative from my past experience is we intercept the application code that does the CRUD operations and log down the events. For my case, we use Spring AOP to write custom log events to another auditing DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `oplog` or `system log`  to determine whether there is a recent data update.

**via oplog**

```
> db.oplog.rs.findOne()
{
  "ts" : Timestamp(1419392438, 1),
  "h" : NumberLong("344552618xxxxxxxx"),
  "v" : 2,
  "op" : "n",
  "ns" : "",
  "o" : {
    "msg" : "Reconfig set",
    "version" : 3
  }
}
```

**Some cloud platform service providers will save the operation log in collection `system.profile`**

```
>db.getCollection("system.profile").findOne({})

{
    "op" : "command",
    "ns" : "fcg_daxxxxxe.xxxx",
    "command" : {
        "findAndModify" : "xxxx",
        "query" : {
            "status" : 0
        },
        "update" : {
            "$set" : {
                "status" : 1
            }
        },
        "lsid" : {
            "id" : UUID("897xxxxxx-c268-49b7")
        },
        "$clusterTime" : {
            "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1607611793, 20),
            "signature" : {
                "hash" : BinData(0,"5UEvkxxxxxxxxEzApUuC1AdsAFo="),
                "keyId" : 686971650xxxxxx94
            }
        },
        "$db" : "fcg_daxxxxxe",
        "$readPreference" : {
            "mode" : "primary"
        }
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 17,
    "nMatched" : 0,
    "nModified" : 0,
    "numYield" : 1,
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : 2,
                "w" : 2
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : 2
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "w" : 2
            }
        }
    },
    "responseLength" : 217,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 246,
    "planSummary" : "COLLSCAN",
    "execStats" : {
        "stage" : "UPDATE",
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 250,
        "works" : 20,
        "advanced" : 0,
        "needTime" : 19,
        "needYield" : 0,
        "saveState" : 1,
        "restoreState" : 1,
        "isEOF" : 1,
        "invalidates" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nWouldModify" : 0,
        "nInvalidateSkips" : 0,
        "wouldInsert" : false,
        "fastmodinsert" : false,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "status" : {
                    "$eq" : 0
                }
            },
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 250,
            "works" : 19,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 18,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 1,
            "restoreState" : 1,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 17
        }
    },
    "ts" : ISODate("2020-12-10T22:49:53.376+08:00"),
    "client" : "xx.xxx.xxx.xx",
    "allUsers" : [
        {
            "user" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ],
    "user" : "root@admin"
}
```

**via system log**

```
# cat  config file and found log path
>cat /etc/mongod.conf   # or /usr/local/mongodb/mongodb.conf (your mongo config file path)
...
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: "/data/mongodb/log/mongodb.log"
  logAppend: true
...

>tail -f /data/mongodb/log/mongodb.log
```